# only scroll childs of specific div class HTML

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have write below code :

```
<body>
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">

</div>
<div id="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div id="nav_drawer">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10" id="table_container">
            <div class="div_table" data-url="/getDevice">
          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to scroll only id : table_container
Is there any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi. give css code pls

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much additional context around what you're trying to do, but if you're simply after the relevant CSS to make an element display it's overflow in a scrollable area it would be:

```
div#table_container {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

However, this will only take effect if the content within #table_container actually overflows the height or width set on the container. You'd likely need to specify such a set height or width, but again without seeing your existing CSS it's hard to comment further.

You can also specify scroll in only the x or y dimension using the overflow-x and overflow-y properties respectively. Read up on the overflow property:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to set overflow-y property for vertical scroll.

```
#table_container{
width:500px;
height: 110px; 
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}